# Use Methods Data in It's Attribute class

Tags: c#, class, methods, attributes

I wrote a function that has an attribute. I want to pass some data to it's attribute and It uses these data to do some work.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CheckXAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CheckXAttribute(int data1, bool data2, byte[] data3)
    {
        someWork(data1, data2, data3);
    }
}
```

some of these data are specified in coding time. but one of them will specify in run-time. I want to pass this data to my method and then use this data in method's attribute.

```
[CheckX(5, true, data3)]
void myMethod(byte[] data3){
    // Some Work
}

...

byte[] data = ...;
myMethod(data);
```

Is it possible? Or is there other way to reach to my goal???

OR ...
Is there a way to send data to the class that contains myMethod, then use this data in method's attribute? Like this.

```
byte[] data = ...;
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(data);
myClass.myMethod();

...

class MyClass {
    public byte[] savedData;
    public MyClass(data)
    {
        this.savedData = data;
    }

    [CheckX(5, true, savedData)]
    void myMethod(){
        // Some Work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, attribute parameters are evaluated at compile time, you need to use compile time constants.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because the attributes are verified before the compilation of source code, so they can't use run-time data.